# Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack

Tags: script

### Screenshots

[image]

---

[image]      [image]

---

[image] [image]

### About

This small UserScript is designed to enhance the Code Golf SE site by making it easier to see the length of each entry and the current winner as far as smallest code size goes.

As the script grew larger, more features were added, such as the ability to sort the answers by the size of the code they contained as well as an automatic update feature (not a very common thing for UserScripts!).

*Note: More information about the script [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170/code-golf-userscript-to-help-in-navigating-the-site-v0-29-now-available).*

#### License

[MIT License](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opensource.org%2Flicenses%2Fmit-license.php&ei=jotbTd6tDZCqsAOOrd2sCg&usg=AFQjCNHk9XmzogLxmjoJbqtCEhhL12gJ4Q)

#### Download

You can get it here: http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/codegolf/count_it.user.js

#### Platform

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. Reported to work on Safari with GreaseKit.

### Contact

Written by me - admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

Written in JavaScript. Any help is welcome!

Comment: The download link is broken; clicking it results in a `404 Not Found` HTTP error. Where to find this script?

Comment: The download link is still broken.

Comment: The download link is still broken. I'm assuming this is abandoned.