# Show length of code blocks (mainly for codegolf.SE)

Tags: script

### Description

This is a small userscript I made that shows the amount of characters in a code block above it. It is mainly for the http://codegolf.stackexchange.com site.

### Screenshot

(This is just some random answer on codegolf.SE.)

[image]

### Code

(minified)

```
$("pre code").each(function(){$(this).parent().before('<div style="border: 1px dotted #C0D4DB; border-bottom: none; border-radius: 5px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; padding: 3px; font: 12px monospace; display: inline; background-color: #F7FDFF; margin-left: 5px">'+$(this).text().trim().replace(/&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&#039;/g," ").length+" chars</div>")})
```

Type `javascript:` in the URL bar, and paste this after it. (or just paste it into the console)

### Userscript

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/178565

Comment: I wrote [a similar script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) a long time back but later abandoned it. I like the style of yours.

Comment: Just a bit of clarification if you don't mind:  `/&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&#039;/g`. Wouldn't this not count characters when someone uses html entities for codegolf?

Comment: @user689 It replaces them with spaces, so it still counts them.

Comment: But it would count them as a 1 character and not 4. Why are you using this in the first place?

Comment: @user689 Because they *are* one character, not 4. If I didn't have that they would be counted as 4.

Comment: Userscript link is b0rked - where can we obtain this?