# Code Golf SE answer sorter

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of Code Golf SE answer sorter user script]

### About

This script adds a "shortest" tab to pages on the [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.  Clicking the tab will sort answers in decreasing order by the length of the first code block in the answer.  It was written as a simple replacement for the [original codegolf.SE user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) that broke with the new Stack Exchange top bar.

The new tab functions pretty much like the normal "active", "oldest" and "votes" tabs, except for a couple of small quirks:

- The information about whether or not the new tab is selected is stored in your browser.  It is thus not synchronized across multiple browsers or computers.
- If there are so many answers (over 30, currently) that they get split over multiple pages, the script will only re-sort the answers on the currently visible page; it will not pull answers from other pages, even if they might have a lower golf score.
- Related to the above, since the choice of which answers are visible on the page may depend on the actual server-side sorting order active before the script runs, this is indicated by a small dashed yellow line under the corresponding tab.  To change the server-side sorting mode, click one of the other tabs and then click "shortest" again.
- Deleted answers and answers with a voting score of -3 or less are always sorted to the end of the page.  (Technically, the sorting code ignores them entirely.)  Answers that include a code block, however long, are always sorted before answers that don't.  Answers with equal golf score are sorted randomly.  The accepted answer is currently *not* always sorted first.

#### License

This script is released into the public domain per the [Creative Commons CC0 public domain dedication](//creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/).  Feel free to do whatever you want with it.

#### Download / Install

This user script is [hosted on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466).  If you have a suitable user script management extension (such as [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox or [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) for Chrome) installed, clicking the ["download / install"](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466/raw/267df3d186d00e9ae874ff911e5f20ed6078529d/codegolf_sorter.user.js) button below should bring up a dialog asking you if you want to install this user script:

> ## [<kbd>Download / Install</kbd>](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466/raw/267df3d186d00e9ae874ff911e5f20ed6078529d/codegolf_sorter.user.js)
>
> <sup>[view source](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/9b55e1f96ee129d53466)</sup>

For more information on how to install user scripts, see the [script tag wiki](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info).

#### Compatibility

This user script has been tested on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome.  It should work on any browser with a compatible user script API, including Opera and Safari.  Please report any incompatibilities you may find.

#### Links

- The original [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](https://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) by Nathan Osman; apparently no longer maintained, does not work with the new SE top bar.
- [Show length of code blocks](https://stackapps.com/questions/4342/show-length-of-code-blocks-mainly-for-codegolf-se) by Doorknob; works very nicely together with this script.
- [Discussion of this script on Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta SE.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/900/we-have-a-new-user-script)

Comment: One of these days, I will update that UserScript. But it's great to hear that users have a suitable replacement in the mean time.